# MFC: Serialize pointer to array of bytes?

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc

Trying to stick within the MFC framework, what is the correct way to handle a pointer to bytes in `serialize()`?   For example, say you have:

```
PBYTE m_TheData; 
SIZE_T m_TheDataSize;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to do this with the `CArchive` `<<` and `>>` operators?

Comment: I can do that for m_TheDataSize but it doesn't know the length of m_TheData so how could that work?  I didn't use a `CByteArray` which could tell.  I just have a pointer to some data.

Comment: For writing: first write the data size, then use `ar.Write(m_TheData, (int)(m_TheDataSize))`. For reading: read the size, create the data (with `new`), then use ar.Read(…)`.

Comment: you should add it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class override of `Serialize()`, you can read/write your `m_TheData` byte array member - *along with its size* - with code like the following:

```cpp
void MyClass::Serialize(CArchive &ar)
{
    CDocument::Serialize(ar); // Replace "CDocument" with your IMMEDIATE base class!
    // Note: the "SIZE_T" type varies between 32- and 64-bit platforms/builds ...
    uint64_t dsFixed; // ... use this to guarantee a 64-bit 'size' write/read!
    if (ar.IsStoring()) {
        //... Write other stuff...
        // ...making sure you keep STRICT order compliance between write and read
        dsFixed = uint64_t(m_TheDataSize);
        ar << dsFixed; // Write the array size first...
        ar.Write(m_TheData, INT(m_TheDataSize)); // ...then the data
        //...
    }
    else {
        //... Read other stuff (see note above)
    //  delete m_TheData;    // Do this if it's not a newly-created class?
        ar >> dsFixed; // Read the array size first...
        m_TheDataSize = SIZE_T(dsFixed);
        m_TheData = new BYTE[m_TheDataSize]; // Allocate space for the data...
        ar.Read(m_TheData, UINT(m_TheDataSize)); // ...then load data from archive
        //...
    }
    return;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

**Note on the `SIZE_T` type:**
Although used in much the same way as the standard `size_t` type, the `MSVC`-specific `SIZE_T` is defined (in `basetsd.h`, included indirectly by `Windows.h` or `afxwin.h`) as follows: `typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;`, where `ULONG_PTR` is itself defined as either `typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR;` (64-bit builds) or `typedef unsigned long ULONG_PTR;` (32-bit builds).

Comment: Why `SIZE_T` and not `size_t`?

Comment: Also this: `CDocument::Serialize(ar); // Replace "CDocument" with your IMMEDIATE base class!` is not very clear...

Comment: @Jabberwocky OP used `SIZE_T`, which I why I did. I added the base-class `Serialize()` to give the quoted function some semblance of usability (it's a common 'mistake' to omit it, even though M/S docs say you should call it).